# Every link starts download in browser on my osx

Tags: macos

After cleaning my keyboard and track pad with and hot cloth (It was greasy), I'm not able to browse any links in Chrome, Safari on my mac book air with El Capitan osx.

When clicking any links on any website, it always starts an download with "download.html". I'm able to browse by right clicking on track-pad and choose "open in new tab", which is very annoying in the long run.

I have somehow managed to alter some config on my machine, but don't know what I have done.

I have tried to google this problem but I don't even succeed in asking the correct question, every result on google returns my with some irrelevant subjects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Was the hot cloth or the keyboard greasy?

Comment: You don't change settings by cleaning things; you can cause damage to things by not cleaning them properly and carefully.  I would start to diagnose the problem by turning off Gestures in System Preferences >> Trackpad.  See if the problem goes away

Answer (score 4):

If your cleaning project stuck your Option key, such that Safari thinks it is always pressed, then any link you click on will download instead of open.

So, try wiggling or drying around your Option key?

Comment: Thank you sincerely, my wife is just mad about me "WTH you've done to my Mac, every link becomes a download", and I did install something some moment ago, so I quickly grabbed my PC and luckily found your answer, "It's your chips crumb, honey, it stucked your Option"